# Partial Differential Equations to Describe Electric Current's Motion

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am a newbie in PDE. I know that Navier-Stokes equations are used to describe the **motion** of viscous fluid substances, what are the equivalent partial differential equations that are used to describe the motion of electric current in wires?

Comment: There are many many models of electric conductivity, each using a different sets of equations. It depends on the problem at hand: size of the system, magnitude of the electric fields involved, etc. Whether or not to take quantum effects into account, nonlinear effects and such. Are you interested in ordinary power wires we have in our houses or something else?

Comment: @YuriyS. Thank you for clarifying the question. I would like to study wires going to electrical substations not normal wires to houses if that is okay to ask?

Comment: Abraheem, I think there's not much difference to be honest. Usually, in this case for alternating current one uses Maxwell equations together with Ohm's law to describe this kind of wires. No nonlinear or quantum effects are present. I think, even telegraph equations will suffice. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations

Comment: @YuriyS. Thank you very much. So, in my case, I need to study telegraph equations to study the motion of electric current to electrical substations.

Comment: I'm pretty sure yes, at least that's what I remember from my college studies on the topic. I think the Wiki page should have enough references to clarify in any case. Telegraph equations are a particular simplification of Maxwell equations

Comment: Thank you Mr. Yuriy.

Comment: You're welcome. There's also a very well known book Andre Ango. "Mathematics for electrical and radio engineers", which should have all the necessary information. It's old though, so nothing about computer programs etc.

Comment: @YuriyS. Thank you very much.